# Passing data to next ViewController

Tags: swift

I am moving to next screen using this code

```
var nextVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainVC") as ViewController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)<br>
```

now i want to pass boolean value in to next screen how can i pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set the variable? You already have the viewController instance.

```
var nextVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainVC") as ViewController

nextVC.myFancyBoolVariable = true

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into `prepareForSegue(_:sender:)` documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/prepareForSegue:sender:).

Comment: can I pass Bool Para with my existing Code? or I must have to use prepareForSegue(_:sender:) ?

Answer (score 0):

Send data from ViewController1 to ViewController2:

ViewController1:

```
// define var    
var myboolvar: Bool = true
var anyOtherVar: String = "test"

// prepare
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if (segue.identifier == "editCardSet"){ // name your segue in storyboard
            var upcoming: ViewController2 = segue.destinationViewController as ViewController2 // set the target ViewController


            // transport any data, as many as you need
            // make sure these vars are set in the seocnd ViewController, otherwise you will get an error here
            upcoming.receiveMyBool = self.myboolvar
            upcoming.receiveMyVar = self.anyOtherVar


        }

    }
```

In ViewController2:

```
class ViewController2: UITableViewController {

// define the vars you are sending from the previous controller
var receiveMyBool: Bool!
var receiveMyVar: String!
```